# Proving a definite integral is finite

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, piecewise-continuity

I have a integral which I have to prove is finite.

$$\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \left(\frac{x \cos x-\sin x}{x^2}\right)^2 dx $$

call the function inside $g(x)$, where $g(x) = (f'(x))^2$ and where $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ more explicitly the function $f(x)$ is piece-wise that is:

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ f(x) =  \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin x}{x} \ \  \text{for } x \neq 0  \\ \ \ 1 \ \ \ \ \  \text{for} \ x = 0
 \end{cases} $

This implies

$$\rightarrow \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  g(x) = \begin{cases} \left(\frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^2}\right)^2 \ \ \text{for} \ x \neq0 \\  \ \ \ \ \ \ \  0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{for} \ x = 0
 \end{cases} $$

Again correct me if the leap of logic from $f(x) \rightarrow g(x)$ does not make sense given that $g(x) = (f'(x))^2$.

Given that the above was done correctly it can be shown (using L'Hopital's ) that the function is continuous everywhere including $x = 0$. My logic is that since this function is well behaved (never goes to infinity) is continuous everywhere on the interval from $[-\pi,\pi]$ and the integral is over a finite domain. Therefore the integral must be finite. I have never heard of a theorem explicitly stating these conditions but let me know if this is true.

(The graph of $g(x)$ below)[image]

Comment: Yes, $g$ can be extended to a continuous function over $[-\pi,\pi]$. Then see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90939/is-the-definite-integral-over-a-continuous-function-always-finite

Comment: Does the piecewise quality extend to $g(x)$ as a consequence of $f(x)$ being a piecewise function as well?

Comment: Sorry, I mean $g$... Anyway if $f$ is continuous then $f^2$ is continuous too.

Comment: Once you know the function is continuous on a closed interval, you know it has an upper and lower bound. In this particular case, the lower bound is $0$ and the integral will not exceed the area of the bounding rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to show that there are a finite number of points that are unbounded.  In fact, the only point that is undefined is $x=0$.  Note that $g(x)\in[0,1]$ for all $x\in[-\pi,\pi]\backslash 0$.  (There are, of course, better bounds, but these are fine.)

Since the function is bounded on a compact set except for a finite set of points, the integral is bounded.